# pinv(H) is not equal to pinv(H'*H)*H'

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm testing the `y = SinC(x)` function with single hidden layer feedforward neural networks (SLFNs) with 20 neurons.

With a SLFN, in the output layer, the output weight(OW) can be described by

```
OW = pinv(H)*T
```

after adding regularized parameter `gamma`, which

```
OW = pinv(I/gamma+H'*H)*H'*T
```

with

```
gamma -> Inf, pinv(H'*H)*H'*T == pinv(H)*T, also pinv(H'*H)*H' == pinv(H).
```

But when I try to calculate `pinv(H'*H)*H'` and `pinv(H)`, I find a huge difference between these two when neurons number is over 5 (under 5, they are equal or almost the same).

For example, when `H` is `10*10` matrix, `cond(H) = 21137561386980.3`, `rank(H) = 10`,

```
H = [0.736251410036783  0.499731137079796   0.450233920602169   0.296610970576716   0.369359425954153   0.505556211442208   0.502934880027889   0.364904559142718   0.253349959726753   0.298697900877265;
0.724064281864009   0.521667364351399   0.435944895257239   0.337878535128756   0.364906002569385   0.496504064726699   0.492798607017131   0.390656915261343   0.289981152837390   0.307212326718916;
0.711534656474153   0.543520341487420   0.421761457948049   0.381771374416867   0.360475582262355   0.487454209236671   0.482668250979627   0.417033287703137   0.329570921359082   0.315860145366824;
0.698672860220896   0.565207057974387   0.407705930918082   0.427683127210120   0.356068794706095   0.478412571446765   0.472552121296395   0.443893207685379   0.371735862991355   0.324637323886021;
0.685491077062637   0.586647027111176   0.393799811411985   0.474875155650945   0.351686254239637   0.469385056318048   0.462458480695760   0.471085139463084   0.415948455902421   0.333539494486324;
0.672003357663056   0.607763454504209   0.380063647372632   0.522520267708374   0.347328559602877   0.460377531907542   0.452395518357816   0.498449772544129   0.461556360076788   0.342561958147251;
0.658225608290477   0.628484290731116   0.366516925684188   0.569759064961507   0.342996293691614   0.451395814182317   0.442371323528726   0.525823695636816   0.507817005881821   0.351699689941632;
0.644175558300583   0.648743139215935   0.353177974096445   0.615761051907079   0.338690023332811   0.442445652121229   0.432393859824045   0.553043275759248   0.553944175102542   0.360947346089454;
0.629872705346690   0.668479997764613   0.340063877672496   0.659781468051379   0.334410299080102   0.433532713184646   0.422470940392161   0.579948548513999   0.599160649563718   0.370299272759337;
0.615338237874436   0.687641820315375   0.327190410302607   0.701205860709835   0.330157655029498   0.424662569229062   0.412610204098877   0.606386924575225   0.642749594844498   0.379749516620049];

T=[-0.806458764562879 -0.251682808380338 -0.834815868451399 -0.750626822371170 0.877733363571576 1 -0.626938984683970 -0.767558933097629 -0.921811074815239 -1]';
```

There is a huge difference between `pinv(H'*H)*H*T` and `pinv(H)*T`, where

```
pinv(H'*H)*H*T = [-4803.39093243484   3567.08623820149    668.037919243849  5975.10699147077  
                   1709.31211566970  -1328.53407325092  -1844.57938928594 -22511.9388736373  
                  -2377.63048959478  31688.5125271114]';

pinv(H)*T = [-19780274164.6438 -3619388884.32672 -76363206688.3469 16455234.9229156
             -135982025652.153 -93890161354.8417 283696409214.039 193801203.735488
             -18829106.6110445 19064848675.0189]'.
```

I also find that if I round `H` , `round(H,2)`, `pinv(H'*H)*H*T` and `pinv(H)*T` return the same answer. So I guess one of the reason might be the float calculation issue inside the matlab.

But since `cond(H)` is large, any small change of `H` may result in large difference in the inverse of `H`. I think the `round` function may not be a good option to test. As Cris Luengo mentioned, with large `cond`,the numerical imprecision will affect the accuracy of inverse.

In my test, I use 1000 training samples `Input:[-10,10]`, with noise between `[-0.2,0.2]`, and test samples are noise free. 20 neurons are selected. The `OW = pinv(H)*T`can give reasonable results for `SinC` training, while the performance for `OW = pinv(H'*H)*T` is worse. Then I try to increase the precision of `H'*H` by `pinv(vpa(H'*H))`, there's no significant improvement.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: How does `neurons=20` influence the size of `H`? How many rows and how many columns are we talking about here? Could you post an actual example of an `H` here you see a difference?

Comment: just to rule out all the conjugate/transpose notation issues, is `H` real?

Comment: So from the edit, `size(H)` is `[100 20]`.  Can you also post `rank(H)`?

Comment: Without regard to the neuron networks, the calculation of `pinv(H)` and `pinv(H'*H)*H'` doesn't return the same result.

Comment: Yes, with such a large condition number, I'm not surprised that inverses are highly inaccurate. The gigantic differences you are seeing are the result of numerical imprecision (i.e. rounding errors).

Answer (score 1):

After some research, the answer is that  ELM is very sentive to scaling and activation function.

Please refer to this paper for details: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2797143.2797161

And paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8533625 demonstrated a noval algorithm to improve the perforamance of ELM for scaling.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer!